# Should I keep apostrophes in this case?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

Do I need to keep apostrophes in the following sentence?:

> Introduction of the four-day working week worked to everyone's
> advantage, both the employee**s'** and the company'**s**.

Or can I simply drop them?:

> Introduction of the four-day working week worked to everyone's
> advantage, both the employee**s** and the compan**y**.

Comment: Keep them. "Advantage" is what "both" describes, so two groups of people doesn't make sense

Comment: I would rather write "Introduction of the four-day working week worked to the advantage of the employees and the company."